# jquery function to find an entered value is text or number and pop error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<SCRIPT>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).each(function(){
var tc = document.getElementsByClassName('tc')[0].value;
var ac = document.getElementsByClassName('ac')[0].value;
  $('.ac').change(function(){
    if ($('.ac').val() > $('.tc').val()){
    alert("  ERROR !!! \n\n The attended classes are more than total classes");}
  });
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).each(function(){
var re = new RegExp("[0-9]");
  $('.tc').change(function(){
  if ($('.tc').val().match(re)) { // DO NOTHING} 
  else {
    alert(" Please enter only numbers ");
  }
   });
});
});
</script>
```

The above function works once or may not at all
if once the value is correct and next the value
is not a number means it doest alert at all
is there something missing or wrong about the
code i have written?????

```
<table width="928" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th width="126">MONTH</th>
    <th colspan="2"><div align="center">Dec</div></th>
    <th colspan="2"><div align="center">Jan</div></th>
    <th colspan="2"><div align="center">Feb</div></th>
    <th colspan="2"><div align="center">Mar</div></th>
    <th colspan="2"><div align="center">Apr</div></th>
    <th colspan="2"><div align="center">May</div></th>
    <th colspan="2"><div align="center">Jun</div></th>
    <th colspan="3"><div align="center">I A</div></th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><div align="center">DETAILS</div></th>
    <th width="43"><div align="center">TC</div></th>
    <th width="43"><div align="center">AC</div></th>
    <th width="43"><div align="center">TC</div></th>
    <th width="43"><div align="center">AC</div></th>
    <th width="43"><div align="center">TC</div></th>
    <th width="43"><div align="center">AC</div></th>
    <th width="43"><div align="center">TC</div></th>
    <th width="43"><div align="center">AC</div></th>
    <th width="43"><div align="center">TC</div></th>
    <th width="43"><div align="center">AC</div></th>
    <th width="43"><div align="center">TC</div></th>
    <th width="43"><div align="center">AC</div></th>
    <th width="43"><div align="center">TC</div></th>
    <th width="43"><div align="center">AC</div></th>
    <th width="64"><div align="center">T1</div></th>
    <th width="64"><div align="center">T2</div></th>
    <th width="72"><div align="center">T3</div></th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Subject-1</th>
    <td><input name="dec_tc_s1" type="text" class="tc"  value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="dec_ac_s1" class="ac" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan_tc_s1" class="tc" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan_ac_s1" class="ac" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="feb_tc_s1" class="tc" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="feb_ac_s1" class="ac" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="mar_tc_s1" class="tc" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="mar_ac_s1" class="ac" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="apr_tc_s1" class="tc" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="apr_ac_s1" class="ac" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="may_tc_s1" class="tc" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="may_ac_s1" class="ac" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jun_tc_s1" class="tc" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jun_ac_s1" class="ac" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="s1_t1"   value="" size="5" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="s1_t2"   value="" size="5" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="s1_t3"   value="" size="5" /></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Subject-2 </th>
    <td><input type="text" name="dec_tc_s2" class="tc" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="dec_ac_s2" class="ac"  value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan_tc_s2" class="tc" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan_ac_s2" class="ac" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="feb_tc_s2" class="tc" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="feb_ac_s2" class="ac" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="mar_tc_s2" class="tc" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="mar_ac_s2" class="ac" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="apr_tc_s2" class="tc" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="apr_ac_s2" class="ac" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="may_tc_s2" class="tc" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="may_ac_s2" class="ac" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jun_tc_s2" class="tc" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jun_ac_s2" class="ac" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="s2_t1" value="" size="5" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="s2_t2" value="" size="5" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="s2_t3" value="" size="5" /></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Subject-3 </th>
    <td><input type="text" name="dec_tc_s3" class="tc"value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="dec_ac_s3" class="ac"value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan_tc_s3" class="tc"value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan_ac_s3" class="ac" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="feb_tc_s3" class="tc"value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="feb_ac_s3" class="ac" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="mar_tc_s3" class="tc"value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="mar_ac_s3" class="ac" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="apr_tc_s3" class="tc" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="apr_ac_s3" class="ac" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="may_tc_s3" class="tc"value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="may_ac_s3" class="ac" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jun_tc_s3" class="tc" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jun_ac_s3" class="ac" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="s3_t1" value="" size="5" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="s3_t2" value="" size="5" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="s3_t3" value="" size="5" /></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Subject-4 </th>
    <td><input type="text" name="dec_tc_s4" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="dec_ac_s4" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan_tc_s4" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan_ac_s4" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="feb_tc_s4" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="feb_ac_s4" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="mar_tc_s4" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="mar_ac_s4" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="apr_tc_s4" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="apr_ac_s4" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="may_tc_s4" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="may_ac_s4" value="" size="3" /></td>

    <td><input type="text" name="jun_tc_s4" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jun_ac_s4" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="s4_t1" value="" size="5" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="s4_t2" value="" size="5" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="s4_t3" value="" size="5" /></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="15"><div align="center">Practicals</div></th>
    <th><div align="center">T1</div></th>
    <th><div align="center">T2</div></th>
    <th><div align="center">REC</div></th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Subject-5 </th>
    <td><input type="text" name="dec_tc_s5" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="dec_ac_s5" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan_tc_s5" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan_ac_s5" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="feb_tc_s5" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="feb_ac_s5" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="mar_tc_s5" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="mar_ac_s5" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="apr_tc_s5" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="apr_ac_s5" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="may_tc_s5" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="may_ac_s5" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jun_tc_s5" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jun_ac_s5" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="s5_t1" value="" size="5" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="s5_t2" value="" size="5" /></td>
    <td><input name="s5_t3" type="text" value="" size="5" /></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Subject-6 </th>
    <td><input type="text" name="dec_tc_s6" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="dec_ac_s6" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan_tc_s6" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan_ac_s6" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="feb_tc_s6" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="feb_ac_s6" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="mar_tc_s6" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="mar_ac_s6" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="apr_tc_s6" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="apr_ac_s6" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="may_tc_s6" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="may_ac_s6" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jun_tc_s6" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jun_ac_s6" value="" size="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="s6_t1" value="" size="5" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="s6_t2" value="" size="5" /></td>
    <td><input name="s6_t3" type="text" value="" size="5" /></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="18"><div align="center">
      <input type="submit"  class="button" value="Update record" onClick="t1()" />
    </div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
  <input type="hidden" name="idatten" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="user_att_id" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="form1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="username" value="" />
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
$('.percentage').each(function() {
    if(parseInt($(this).html())>100){
    $(this).css('background', '#FFCF87' )
    alert('You Have Entered Attented class more than Total classes');
    }
    else if (parseInt($(this).html())<75){
    $(this).css('background', '#FF9B82');
    }
 });
 $('.iatotal').each(function() {
    if(parseInt($(this).html())>25){
    $(this).css('background', '#FFCF87' )
    alert('You Have Worng number Please check your entry');
    }
    else if (parseInt($(this).html())<10){
    $(this).css('background', '#FF9B82');
    }
 });
 </script>
</html>
```

Comment: `$(document).each(function(){` ?

Comment: What is happening in your code? `$(document).each` and multiple DOM ready statements? Explain the code a little bit!

Comment: hi there i am trying to restrict the entry to text box as numerical and also verify the value of class ac to lesser than class tc where several number of text boxes under both the class are present to submit for database

Comment: but nothing is happning with this code along with this jquery 1.2.6 min.js is also loaded in the page for some work.

Comment: why the vanilla javascript selectors on lines 4 & 5 ?

Comment: Its not an html but its a php

Answer (score 2):

try something like following to loop over the multiple elements in your scenario:

```
<SCRIPT>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.ac').change(function(){
    $('.ac').each(function(index){
      if($('.tc').get(index)) {
        if($('.ac').get(index).val() > $('.tc').get(index).val()) {
          alert("  ERROR !!! \n\n The attended classes are more than total classes");
        }
      }
    });
  });

  var re = new RegExp("[0-9]");
  $('.tc').change(function(){
    if ($(this).val().match(re)) { 
      // DO NOTHING
    } 
    else {
      alert(" Please enter only numbers ");
    }
  });    
});    
</script>
```

Comment: for the first instance in a row the alert happens but for the second instance in the same row doesn't alert even if the text box is not a NAN.This should happen for each and every text boxes on the page. where each row contains 14 textboxes * 7

Comment: can you send the html snip as well to get the better idea

Comment: modified the answer. try it.